# Cytoscape : Add element in setTimeout doesn't get rendered

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

In the following code , I add a node to the graph in `setTimout` but it's not rendered. When I move the code out of `setTimeout` it's drawn. Any reason ?

```
var cytoscape = require('cytoscape');

var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('container'),
    layout: {
        name: 'circle'
    }
});

cy.add({
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
            id: 'id1'
        }
    }
); // this adding is drawn
console.log(cy.nodes()); // this shows that the node with id:id1 is added 

setTimeout(function() {
    cy.add({
            group: "nodes",
            data: {
                id: 'id2'
            }
        }
    ); // this one doesn't get drawn
    console.log(cy.nodes()); // BUT, this shows that the node with id:id2 is added 
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined a position, so the node can't render.  Define the position of nodes explicitly or call layouts explicitly.

Explanation: Assuming this is on init of the page, you've created a race condition:  The graph can't render until `DOMContentLoaded`.  So, the layout is delayed until after that event.  You've created the situation where `id1` is added before the layout and `id2` is added after.  So, `id1` has a position and can be rendered, but `id2` has no position and can't be rendered.

In 2.4.8, nodes will have [a default position of (0, 0)](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1076) to make it easier to avoid mistakes like this.